Get Freeform Submission ID from "Replace Form"
Has anyone managed to get the submission.id from the "Replace form with Success Template" on Freeform using Craft5? I was passing it via the Return URL like so:
        {{ craft.freeform.form( 'downloadForm', {
             returnUrl: "{{ siteUrl }}downloads?submission={{ submission.id }}",
        } ).render() }}

Though, the replaced form doesn't have the notion of a submission and the  {{ dump(craft.app.request.url) }} doesn't seem to get the return URL.
Any help would be great.
